# WordPress moving <span> outside <p>

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have this bit of code on my Wordpress single-post.php file:

```
<p class="author-date">by <a href="#author-box"><?php the_author(); ?></a> on <?php the_date(); ?> <span style="display:inline-block">| Share this article: <?php echo wpfai_social(); ?></span></p>
```

But for some reason the `echo wpfai_social();` bit (which echos an `<ul>`) is moved out of the `<span>` tag when the page is displayed, like:

```
<p class="author-date">by <a href="#author-box">Author Name</a> on Post date <span style="display:inline-block">| Share this article:</span>
<ul id="social-buttons">...</ul></p>
```

Any idea why this happens? Have no clue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML does not allow `<ul>` elements to appear as children of `<span>` elements or `<p>` elements.

The browser is recovering from your error by moving the element outside.

Comment: Oh... I didn't know browsers do those kind of corrections... Good to know. Will replace by a div. Thanks!